# Change from app.py to main.py when deploying a FLASK app in Google App Engine

Tags: python, flask, google-app-engine

I am following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service) to deploy an app in Google App Engine. Everything works correctly.

Nevertheless, Google, by default, looks for the main folder (where `app = Flask(__name__)` is defined) in `main.py`. How could I redefine this? I would like to define this main folder as `app.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Rename `main.py` to `app.py`
2. Add `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app`  to your `app.yaml` file. This is where you are telling Google to find the `app` object in a file called `app`
3. Add `gunicorn` to your `requirements.txt` file

**Notes:**

i. Because you're changing from `main.py` to `app.py`, you need to specify an entrypoint. [GAE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup) says

> If your app meets the following requirements, App Engine will start
> your app with the gunicorn web server if you don't specify the
> entrypoint field:
>
> - The root of your app directory contains a main.py file with a WSGI-compatible object called app.
> - Your app does not contain Pipfile or Pipfile.lock files.

ii. If you add an entrypoint, then you need to include `gunicorn` in your requirements.txt file

iii. I just tested the above configuration (the answer I gave) on a dev environment (Python 3.9 environment on Macbook using dev_appserver.py) and it works